# Can't Reindex All Search Indexes

Tags: liferay

I've recently deleted 120,000 Users from my Liferay database using an automated script. Before that however, I manually deleted 2 Users from the database using **DELETE FROM User_ WHERE userId=1234567** - just to see what might happen with any associations that User might have had.

The User was deleted, but all other table rows holding that userId (1234567) remained. Fine.

So now I'm at a point where I'd like to reindex all search indexes to get a current list of users, but LR throws an exception:

```
08:07:41,922 ERROR [http-bio-20110-exec-290][LuceneIndexer:136] Error encountere
d while reindexing
com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.SearchException: com.liferay.portal.NoSuchUserE
xception: No User exists with the key {contactId=1234568}
       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.BaseIndexer.getDocument(BaseIndexer.j
ava:179)
       at com.liferay.portlet.usersadmin.util.ContactIndexer$1.performAction(Con
tactIndexer.java:203)
  at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.BaseActionableDynamicQuery.performActions
InSingleInterval(BaseActionableDynamicQuery.java:309)
     at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.BaseActionableDynamicQuery.performActi
```

This contactId *seems* to be a single digit higher than the userId for any user created (I could be wrong about that)

So my question is, how can I fix this problem so I can perform the reindex?

Liferay EE 6.2
Tomcat 7.0.33
SQL Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the **contactId** for my manually deleted user was still in the *Contact_* Table. I deleted him from the table and can now perform the reindex. I can now see all the user & user groups after reindexing.

From LR:

> rule #1 with using Liferay - The database is not yours, you should
>   never be in it and you should never be issuing sql against it.
>
> The Liferay API is the only way to modify data. Period.
>
> The Liferay API supports user deletion. Had you used the Liferay API,
>   the users would have been deleted and your indexes, etc., would have
>   been fine.
>
> Okay, I know that's going to come across as a little aggressive or
>   something, but it's important. The whole Liferay system depends upon
>   it's data, so any time you tweak the data manually it potentially
>   breaks the system. If you dig through the actual process that the
>   Liferay API does for a user deletion, you'd see that the "delete from
>   user_ where ..." is just a small part.
>
> I always tell people new to Liferay to just forget that the database
>   exists. It's definitely their database, not yours, and it's not to be
>   messed with.

Comment: This is very close to what I might have written as an answer - in fact, the quoted content might even be my words that you found in a different location :)

Comment: This quote comes from David H Nebinger, who quickly responded to my post on the Liferay forums: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/37253618. I thank you for your input though sir.

Comment: This "rule" would've been obsolete if Liferay had foreign key constraints. Just saying...